# How to add additional kitchen circuits to fuse panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am redesigning my kitchen. I have a log home. I need to put a dishwasher and 4 electrical outlets all in the two walls of new counters. I need to know what fuse for the fuse panel to use for this application.

I am going from the panel to the kitchen for a dishwasher. From that I want to go to four outlets on same walls.

Can I run from dishwasher to the first outlet, and  from that to the next? These will 3 feet apart.

Comment: Eh, you're adding circuits to a *fuse box*?!  Also, where in the world are you?

Comment: Posting photos will help.  Hopefully you don't actually mean "fuse box".  Also the thickness of the existing wires matters.

Answer (score 0):

Fuses are allowed.  But since this is new work, you must follow the National Electrical Code (NEC) in its current version.

- For kitchens there need to be two separate circuits feeding the outlets, and you have to interleave them so outlets from the same circuit aren't all right next to each other.  Not AABB, but ABAB. I recommend doing this in 12 gauge wire since it's barely more expensive than 14 gauge.  If all the wire in the circuit is 12 gauge, it can be fused for 20 amps.
- Kitchen outlets need to be GFCI, which I believe you can accomplish with GFCI outlets.  Those allow you to feed more outlets downstream so you only need two.  GFCI also means you need to wire neutral and ground with each circuit, not casually crossing up neutrals as some have been known to do.
- The dishwasher needs to be on its own circuit.  If using fuses, it can't share a neutral with the garbage disposal, as is commonly done with circuit breakers.

If you want to just staple NM cable to the wall, that is legal.  However if you have easy access now, I suggest you run EMT conduit just as commercial buildings do.  It's more work at first, but makes it ridiculously easy to inspect and service the wiring later.  That's especially useful if you're doing this gypsy without permits.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't connect anything new to a fuse box.  And it's not a good idea.  Keep your old knob & tube wiring, it's probably fine.  But ditch the fuse box completely, turning it into a passive wiring cabinet protected by upstream breakers.

Comment: The code calls for two 20 ampere circuits to feed the kitchen receptacles, so 12 AWG copper (or equivalent) **must** be used.